# ng2-charts angular radar exception

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, radar-chart

i want to display 2 component in a dashboard one radar and the other is line, so i have 3 separate component.

when i implemented the radar component i started to get this exception in the radar component.

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BaseChartDirective -> ThemeService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BaseChartDirective -> ThemeService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ThemeService!
```

i followed the docs provided in here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-radar-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts ..
i have no idea whats causing this problem..

Comment: Which version of angular and ng2-chart are you using?

Comment: angular 8, ng2-chart 2.4.2

Answer (score 13):

finally i'v fixed this problem, only by adding
providers:[ThemeService] in the app.modules.

i think this problem happens only on these version on angular 8 and ng2-chart 2.4.2